# jquery 3 ready function does not work correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, document-ready

Good afternoon!

I moved from jquery 1.11.1 to jquery 3.3.1. I have the following code on the page:
...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function onJqueryLoad() {
    $(function () {
        console.log(document.readyState);
        window.app = new App({logsUrl: '3434'});
    });
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js" defer onload="onJqueryLoad()"></script>
...
// more scripts
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/Common/App.js" defer></script>
```

...
In the console I see the following error:

> interactive
>
> jquery-3.3.1.js:3818 jQuery.Deferred exception: App is not defined
>   ReferenceError: App is not defined
>        at HTMLDocument. (http://localhost:53228/:12:35)
>        at mightThrow (http://localhost:53228/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js:3534:29)
>        at process (http://localhost:53228/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js:3602:12) undefined
>
> Uncaught ReferenceError: App is not defined
>        at HTMLDocument. ((index):12)
>        at mightThrow (jquery-3.3.1.js:3534)
>        at process (jquery-3.3.1.js:3602)

It turns out that the contents of `$ (function () {` were called before the App.js script was loaded, and the status of `document.readyState` was “interactive”.

But if you do not use “defer” when importing jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js" onload="onJqueryLoad()"></script>
```

then the console will have the status: “complete” and no problems will arise.
Description of the status `document.readyState` interactive (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState):

> The document has finished loading and the document has been parsed,
>   but sub-resources such as images, stylesheets and frames are still
>   loading.

I failed to find more detailed information on whether the status “interactive” indicates that all scripts are loaded.

I checked it in the latest versions of chrome and firefox, but in Microsoft Edge no problem.

In the earlier version of jquery 1.11.1, there were no such errors.

https://jsfiddle.net/uez1y7ft/4/ - if using without cash, the error appears from time to time(ctrl+f5 - see the console).

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why don't you try in onJqueryLoad: $(document).ready(function(){    });

Comment: Instead of using `onload="onJqueryLoad()"`, you should use `$(function(){ onJqueryLoad(); });`

Comment: Tried it.
Does not help.

Comment: How does 'App' get defined? is there any delay between App.js running and App being defined? What you are experiencing here is a race condition, it's likely the change in jquery version affecting it is just coincidence.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/uez1y7ft/2/ - if using without cash, the error appears from time to time(ctrl+f5 - see the console).

Comment: Please explain why "defer is inportant to me"

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's problem of jquery. You need use `document.AddEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {...});` or fix jquery library.  You can see discussion about this problem here: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/3271

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

I've reordered the scripts, removed the `defer` and `onload` attributes, and have added a line to call onJqueryLoad when jQuery has finished initialising.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/Common/App.js"></script>
<script data-worldcore>
function onJqueryLoad() {
  console.log(document.readyState);
  window.app = new App({logsUrl: '3434'});
}
$(function(){ onJqueryLoad(); } );
</script>
```

Comment: i need "defer". It's important for me.

Comment: @Dmitry Please tell us why